# Retrieve specific information from a web page

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm looking for a way to get specific information from a web page using Qt. So far I have been using the `QNetworkAccessManager` and have managed to get the HTTP response containing everything in the page.

What is now the correct way to filter this information and parse the xml to just get the relevant information? For example, if you wanted to query wikipedia for information, how would you save just the information and not the source code for the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the content, retrieve only the information you need and then store it.

Qt gives you some tools to help doing that.

The [wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_HTML) has more information about that.

You can use the [XML Handling classes](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_Document_Formats) if it's a valid XML, you can use other tool to convert a broken XML HTML page to a valid XML as stated in the [wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_HTML).

To validate and repair HTML files you can use [libTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/libintro.html)